# Keras model outputs constant value as prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm currently implementing a reinforcement learning algorithm, however keras does not seem to want to cooperate. In training I feed the model with batches of data and everything works like its supposed to, but then when I want to use the model for prediction on a single datapoint it just outputs the same value over and over (with varying input). Here my code:

//initialization of network:

```
    def initialize_actor(self):

    state_variable_input = Input(shape=(3, ))

    dense = Dense(16, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="lecun_uniform")(state_variable_input)
    batch_norm1 = BatchNormalization()(dense)
    dense2 = Dense(16, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="lecun_uniform")(batch_norm1)
    batch_norm2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2)
    output = Dense(1, activation=lecun_tanh, kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(-3e-3, 3e-3),
                   bias_initializer=RandomUniform(-3e-3, 3e-3))(batch_norm2)

    model = Model(inputs=state_variable_input,
                  outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

    return model, state_variable_input
```

//training:

```
    def train_actor(self, samples):

    cur_state_var, action, reward, new_state_var = samples
    predicted_actions = self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var]) # shape of cur_state_var (batch_size, 3), predicts n = batch_size actions as intended
    grads = self.sess.run(self.critic_grads, feed_dict={
        self.critic_var_in: cur_state_var,
        self.critic_action_in: predicted_action})[0]

    summ, _  = self.sess.run([self.merged, self.optimize], feed_dict={
        self.actor_var_in: cur_state_var,
        self.actor_critic_grad: grads
        })
    self.writer.add_summary(summ)
```

//prediction:

```
  def act(self, cur_state_var):

      if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
          return env.action_space.sample()

      else:
          action = self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var], batch_size=1)[0] # shape of cur_state_var = (1,3), the network returns the same value for action at every call
          return action
```

I hope my mistake can be found somewhere in the code I think is relevant to this. I suspect that it has to do with the different batch sizes at training and prediction time. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3):

I often encounter this problems, and one of the reason is the samples' feature is not balanced. For example, the feature is like this:

```
[1234, 0.001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.01]
```

As you can see, the first column feature is to big, the other features is too small, so you should do something like Normalized Features.

And another reason maybe the activation is wrong, you should check the activation according to your specific work, especially the last layer's activation.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already considered your first point and my data was already min-max scaled.

Mean 1st component: -0.364490946837
StdDev 1st component: 0.609148434557
Min 1st component: -0.999999987686
Max 1st component: 0.999999970844

Mean 2nd component: 0.0009056560424
StdDev 2nd component: 0.704332105003
Min 2nd component: -0.999999999711
Max 2nd component: 0.999999993432

Mean 3rd component: -0.00216107064395
StdDev 3rd component: 0.45353269543
Min 3rd component: -1.0
Max 3rd component: 1.0

Do you think I should also zero-center?

Comment: As to you second point, the activation function I'm using is the modified tanh from the "efficient backprop" paper by LeCun. It works fine as long as I supply a batch of inputs and I've also verified that the same occurs when using standard tanh

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer; this solved my problem.